# PHP Help Needed

Tags: php, ftp

Guys I have one folder called "w", In this folder I have one file that need to go to the folder "forum" that is located not inside the "w" folder but inside the root folder (whete the "file.php" is located). How go here? I used "./forum/" is it correct?

Dir Structure:

```
|---file.php
|---w
|---forum
```

here the code:

```
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = '/forum/'; //relative path to phpBB3 forum directory
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
```

I need to set that the $phpbb_root_path go to the folder forum when the file that have this code is not in the root but in the folder "w"

Resolved! :D the ../forum/ worked!!!!!
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't made it clear what you are trying to do but When representing file locations a '.' represents the current directory. To represent the next higher directory use '..' ie. to go to the folder '~/web/forum' from inside '~/web/w' the path would be '../forum'

Comment: I'm inside the folder "w" that is inside the root folder. I want to select one folder that is not inside the w folder but inside the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to define the root of the site, and then continue your file path from there, like so:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/W/';
```

Or, if you are going to be using the root multiple times, define it as something shorter:

```
$root=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

So that the path then becomes:

```
$root.'/W/';
```

Just keep in mind that the . between the root and the rest of the file path is NOT part of the file path. It just separates the $_SERVER or $root part from the rest of the file path.

EDIT: In response to your edit:

Use either `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/forum/';` or `'../forum/';`

Comment: I need just one location. I'm using ./forum but it isnt correct because the file that have ./forum is in the folder "w" and the folder "forum" is not in the folder "w" but in the root folder.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the question. You have a file in W that needs to go to Forum. When you say that it needs to go there, are you saying that you want to run a script that can move it from W to Forum? Or are you just wondering how a file in one folder can interact with a file in another folder that is not a subfolder? If the latter, the answer is with using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. If not, you might have to clarify a little more.

Comment: I'm wondering how a file in one folder can interact with a file in another folder that is not a subfolder

Comment: Then the answer is already above. You can also use `..` to represent going up one level. It's up to you. Unless you want to provide the code that you are trying to get to work, that's about all I can do to help you.

Comment: Use either `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/forum/';` or `'../forum/';`